# Printing a document over application --> WCF Service. Can I access local printers?

Tags: c#, wcf, printing

I have an application running which has a WCF backend.
Everything is working great, except for one thing, printing documents!

Basically I have a `LocalReport` (`Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport`, .rdlc file) which lives on the server, and gets a command to print from the app client.
The server populates the report and prints it to the printer specified by the client

It works for printing to network printers, but I would like to be able to print to local printers (specifically the 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer', it just times-out when I try, which is understandable).

The `LocalReport` has it's contents populated from a database, which is why it is done from the server.
It is also used by other applications, which I why I would rather keep it on the server rather than have a local copy.

I've tried having the service return a `PrintDocument` instead, but it doesn't serialize over WCF properly.
My other thought was to convert the `PrintDocument` (or the instance of the `LocalReport`, or even export it to a **PDF**) to a **byte array**, send that to the client, then convert it back and handle the printing.
Seems like a bit of a hack.

But as I am new to the WCF world I wanted to hear if there is a better approach.
Or am I going about things all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport in the client side (WinForms, I assume that you are using). You can add

```
var report = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyReport", GetReportData()));
```

`GetReportData` can make the WCF call and bring in the list of objects that can be rendered as the report. If you do so, report will be generated at the client side and local printers are all available. In fact, it is the standard way of doing reporting as well.